# Subtract integer value with degree, minutes, sec?

Tags: python

How to Subtract integer value with degree, minutes,  sec? Error is coming when I am subtracting two variables.

```
pip install flatlib
```

```
import flatlib
from flatlib import const
from flatlib.chart import Chart
from flatlib.datetime import Datetime
from flatlib.geopos import GeoPos
from flatlib.dignities import accidental
from flatlib.dignities.accidental import AccidentalDignity

date= Datetime('2021/06/23','17:00','+00:00')
pos = GeoPos('38n32', '8w54')
chart = Chart(date, pos)
sun = chart.get(const.SUN)
A = 2
print(sun - A)
```

Required output
+02:26:34-2=0:26:34

Comment: I am not sure the output, and change `+02:26:34-2=0:26:34-2` to `+02:26:34-2=0:26:34` in my understanding.

Comment: Yes you are exactly correct,  your understanding is correct.